# How To Apply CSS rule to Classes with Specific Keywords Inside Them?

Tags: css, css-selectors

That is to say, see the following:

```
<div class="helloeverybody">
</div>
<div class="heyeveryperson">
</div>
```

I want to apply a css rule to every class with the word "every" in it.
Is there a formal name for this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *"contains"* attribute selector by appending an asterisk after the attribute - e.g.

```
div[class*=every] {
    color: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FWP8j/1/

The definition from [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at
>   least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty
>   string then the selector does not represent anything.